# pyinstaller exe created on Windows 8 does not work in Windows 7

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I've made an executable file in Windows 8. It runs properly in Windows 8 and 10. The problem is when I double click the exe file in Windows 7 I get the message "myfile.exe has stopped working". I tested all things which come to my mind but the problems still remains.

[The figure below is the message when I run my exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp5ZW.jpg)

Comment: 32 bit windows 7 vs 64 bit windows 8? You're missing the necessary .NET runtimes? What debug messages can you get out of the program, for instance by executing it from a terminal? in 90% of cases like this *(remember, windows 7 is part of the dinosaur time now, so I don't exactly remember how these errors presents itself)* it's because you're missing a dll somewhere that the compiled runtime expects.

Comment: I also installed the last version of .Net but it did not work

Comment: I've created it in 32 bits  windows 8 and tested it on64 bit  window 7

Comment: You most likely have a missing DLL. It's not about "the latest .NET", it needs to be a specific that your freeze/exe/packer uses to create the exeecutable. One good tool for this is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls - launch your application and see what DLL's it expects.

Comment: apparently ucrtbase.DLL is my problem. So how can I solve the problem?

Comment: You really need to do some investigation yourself. I probably come off as harsh now, and I apologies. I know this community has had issues with people being unfriendly at times. But things like these are well documented, it's easy to find information what that particular dll is, where it comes from and how to solve it. If you're missing a DLL, you need to supply it with your application, that's the bottom line. So we can't really fix this for you. This particular DLL is from MS Visual C++, not a .NET. So figure out what Visual C++ runtime you got on the build machine and..

Comment: Damn comments are to short... and instruct the user to install the same Microsoft Visual C++. Or figure out which VCruntime contains that particular DLL (you can extract them, search or try out) to figure that out and instruct the end user to install the required VC runtime. Because you're most likely not allowed to just copy the dll from one machine to another, because there's TOA and stuff that needs to be accepted prior to use. So you can't just boundle it with your .exe and ship it.

Comment: I have this dll with my exe file.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely that you're missing DLLs on the machine that won't run the executable.

This is due to the fact that some where, some time you've installed either a .NET environment, a Visual XXX environment or a runtime containing a particular set of DDL's for the application to function.

From asking in the questions, it points towards a Visual C++ runtime. That can be installed either via a full set of Visual C++ suit or just a VCruntime *(usually)*.

It's also important to point out that these runtimes come with their own terms of agreements and licenses. That's why they aren't packed in the executable *(also, usually)*. You **can** bundle them in your executable, depending on which freeze technique you use, but it's not allowed and you need to have permission to do so.

One way of doing it (via pyinstaller) is doing:

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data ucrtbase.dll;. myscript.py
```

Again, check with the license if this is allowed.

If you against all odds decide to copy and paste the DLL with your .exe, you need to make sure it's accessible via your Windows `PATH` environment, seeing as that's where your executable will look for the DLLs *(usually system32 or other paths)*. So blindly copying it because someone on the internet said so, doesn't always work. You have to learn and understand why it would work and how it works.

Here's a good external source that describes this phenomena pretty well: https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/

> All solutions need MS Visual C++ dll to be installed on target machine, except py2app. Only Pyinstaller makes self-executable exe that bundles the dll when passing --onefile to Configure.py.